# Dial intent in custiom view

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I trying to make a dial intent in my custom listView.

[image]

I included the permission 
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`
and here's my code

```
case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADRS:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_address,
                        parent, false);

                TextView adrsName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adrsName) ;
                TextView adrsNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.adrsNum) ;
                ImageButton btnDial = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdrs);

                btnDial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel."+Information.phone));
                        if(intent.resolveActivity( context.getPackageManager())!=null){
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                            Log.d("HELP","inside");
                        }
                        Log.d("HELP","clicked!");
                    }
                });
                adrsName.setText(listViewItem.getAdrsName());
                adrsNum.setText(listViewItem.getAdrsNum());
                break;
```

I can see the log "clicked!", but not "inside".I guess it is because `context` of `context.getPackageManager()` and `context.startActivity(intent)`. Since they are what I changed from original code with red line. I also tried `MainActiviy` instead of `context`, It didn't worked.
How can I access to `getPackageManager` and `startActivity` properly?

Comment: Have you tried like this **MainActivity.getPackageManager** ?

Comment: Yes, It didn't work.:(

Comment: Try only the getPackageManager instead of context.getPackageManager

Comment: or use **getActivity().getPackageManager();**

Comment: I tried `getPackageManager` only. it didn't work :(

Comment: **getActivity()** also...I'm thinking about using OnClickedListener instead of Button handler...

Comment: Then give it a try

Comment: I made it by using Listview `setOnItemClickListner`, It wasn't by clicking button though..